# Ubuntu keeps enabling panning and tracking for dual monitor setup

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, xfce

I have two monitors connected to my box (nvidia graphics with proprietary driver). Everything was fine until I updated to saucy (not using default ubuntu desktop but xfce).

After the update the update, both monitors keep showing the same desktop area and when the mouse touches the screen edges, the desktop will be tracked. I can - however - correct this by using `nvidia-settings` and moving the right screen to the right of the left screen, but I have to do this after every start. Even using the "Save to xorg.conf" option in `nvidia-settings` does not do the job.

xrandr before my correction:

```
DVI-I-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm panning 2960x1050+0+0
...
HDMI-0 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm panning 2560x1024+0+0 tracking 2960x1050+0+0 border 0/0/0/0
....
```

and after:

```
DVI-I-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
...
HDMI-0 connected 1280x1024+1680+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
...
```

I even tried to remove the `xorg.conf` at all, started with a clean user profile.

How can I either make the xserver remember the settings or do the correction with `xrandr`?